# Java send http POST with UTF-8

Tags: java, http, post, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send HTTP POST with Google FCM. With code below, it's OK to send English message but Chinese characters. I did many trials by adding UTF-8 here and there... Need help.

The payload of my message is str2 in the code below.
The result shown in Android APP is 
Hello+%E6%88%91

E68891 is the correct UTF-8 code, but I need it to be shown as a Chinese character.

```
package tryHttpPost2;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class TryHttpPost2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=...............");

        String str1 = "{\"to\":\"/topics/1\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"";
        String str2 = URLEncoder.encode("Hello 我", "utf-8");
        String str3 = "\"}}";
        String urlParameters = str1+str2+str3;
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        con.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: URLEncoder is not the right thing for JSON. Encoding in JSON is... a mess. Either you encode the entire thing using the transport layer (and you are probably doing it wrong - looking at you `writeBytes(urlParameters)`) or get some messy encoding with utf-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Do you have some links for the OP showing the correct way to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `writeBytes`: as the Java documentation says:

   > For each character, one byte is written, the low-order byte, in exactly the manner of the writeByte method . The high-order eight bits of each character in the string are ignored.

So this method can not write unicode strings.

2. `URLEncoder` is intended to be used for `GET`requests or `POST` request with the content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But you transmit data using the content-type `application/json`. You somehow try to also use url encoding there, but this does not work. (See the [relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) for more information)

To fix this, use the right method to transfer the data: As utf-8, without any encoding in the JSON:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=...............");

String str1 = "{\"to\":\"/topics/1\",\"notification\":\"title\":\"";
String str2 = "Hello 我";
String str3 = "\"}}";
String urlParameters = str1+str2+str3;
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

wr.write(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
con.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Note that if the `Hello 我` part is user input, you have to escape some characters like ``\`` and `"`.

Comment: My original question missed a brace in str1 before "\"title" and so yours.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Kuhn's great help. Here is what I do now and works.

1. Let Content-Type as just "application/json".
2. Let str2 be just the payload string.
3. Replace writeBytes thing by wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("utf-8"));

   4. The property "Accept-Charset" seems useless here. Works with or without it.